# Why didn't Laurita Tohm get a prosthetic arm?

Tags: star-wars

I just finished the last issue of *Darth Vader and the Ghost Prison 5* and I am wondering, why did Tohm never get a replacement arm? As an aspiring military cadet, It would be in his best interest to do so. So why no cigar?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but I can think of two reasons elsewhere in the Star Wars universe that limb-losers did not get a prosthetic.

[Tenel Ka](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tenel_Ka#A_severe_accident) did not get a prosthetic arm as a personal choice, and chose to compensate with her Force abilities instead.

[Grand Moff Hissa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bertroff_Hissa) was unable to get prosthetic legs because he had lost his legs too close to the hip. (Note that Hissa only appears in a book series that is often considered noncanon by fans, so take that as you will)

It's possible that Tohm chose not to for some reason, or was unable to.